# Magento 2: Get child product name in bundle options along with SKU and ID in API Response

Tags: magento2, catalog, rest-api, bundle

I am working on a headless magento approach.

On hitting : /V1/products/:sku

I get the details of the product as the following response:

```
...
        "bundle_product_options": [
            {
                "option_id": 70,
                "title": "Product title",
                "required": true,
                "type": "select",
                "position": 1,
                "sku": ":sku",
                "product_links": [
                    {
                        "id": "1059",
                        "sku": ":sku",
                        "option_id": 70,
                        "qty": 1,
                        "position": 1,
                        "is_default": false,
                        "price": 0,
                        "price_type": 0,
                        "can_change_quantity": 0
                    },

           .....
```

I want to add the option's title in the products_links section.

I also need this for configurable products as well.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I think I have to add a method to getTitle in the

> vendor/magento/module-bundle/Api/Data/LinkInterface.php

But I don't know how to do that.